# (NGINX) NodeJS Reverse Proxy Subdomain

Tags: node.js, nginx, web, nginx-reverse-proxy

This question has probably been asked a lot, but I can't seem to find a really simple solution that actually works. And I need help to set this up.

**I'll list my current enviroment so you can get a quick overview:**

- Server Host: HETZNER Cloud Server
- Domain Host: Webhuset.no (DNS Records are here)
- OS: CentOS 7 (Hetzner)
- Website: Running NGINX with NodeJS reverse proxy
- DNS: I have not added *.domain.example in my DNS Record, because I don't want every sub-host to to to my server.
- SSL: Enabled, using Let's Encrypt Certbot.

I am only running one site, with of course, different pages for different stuff (Not multiple sites)

My goal is to have something similar to CPanel-subdomains. Where I can add **admin.domain.example** and set it to for example **domain.example/admin** without redirect.

But I have found this to be harder than expected, because I have been reading so many forum-posts and so many docs now and I just can't get it to work.

I have come far enough to understand that the subdomain has to be configured in Nginx. Before this I kept trying to do this in the nodejs config.

My current **nginx.conf** which makes my domain **example.domain** go straight to root folder of my website, with SSL. This works fine.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        server_name example.domain www.example.domain;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    }
}
```

Here I assume I have to add a server block in order to make **admin.example.domain** route to **example.domain/admin**

How can I do this and still maintain SSL? I need SSL in order to make the images render.
I have tried adding a server block like this:

```
 server {
    server_name admin.example.domain

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

If this were to work *(It doesn't unless I listen to port 80 and use http://)*, it would just redirect me to **(UNSECURE)https://admin.example.domain/admin**

And everybody who do the same as I just did above, gets it to work. But I don't. What is different, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you aware that you'll need different certificates for `admin.example.domain` and `example.domain` respectively (unless you have a wildcard certificate)…?

Comment: Well damn, this actually solved everything. I remember attempting this, and it gave me an error that I didn't understand but after doing it again I just understood it. I had to add a server block, before running certbot. And now it displays admin.domain.example in the URL and renders the /admin page perfectly. Only con is the font doens't load because of a header error, but I just directly added the font from Google Fonts and it solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION

- Create a server block for each subdomain I want and put the directory in the proxy_pass (Save and restart/reload nginx config)
- Run certbot --nginx
- Select the subdomain from the certbot list
- Go through with the configuration and boom it works as expected.

Comment: could you share a reference link to the docs?

Comment: I figured this out myself with the help of @slauth's comment above. I don't understand the docs so I barely read them as I cannot relate to it in my own code.